# Where to place __all__ in a Python file?

Tags: python, pep8, readability, code-readability, flake8

I am wondering, what the standard placement in a Python file for `__all__`?

My assumption is directly below the import statements.  However, I could not find this explicitly stated/asked anywhere.  So, in general, where should one place `__all__`?

Where would it be put in the below example file?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""Where to put __all__."""

from time import time

# I think it should go here: __all__ = ["Hello"]

SOME_GLOBAL = 0.0


class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#module-level-dunder-names):

> Module level "dunders" (i.e. names with two leading and two trailing underscores) such as `__all__`, `__author__`, `__version__`, etc. should be placed after the module docstring but before any import statements except from `__future__` imports.

So if you're following PEP 8 strictly, you were close. In practice, it's *not* obeyed strictly. A *ton* of the Python "included batteries" modules define `__all__` after the imports, so your approach is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#module-level-dunder-names):

> Module level "dunders" (i.e. names with two leading and two trailing underscores) such as `__all__`, `__author__`, `__version__`, etc. should be placed after the module docstring but before any import statements except from `__future__` imports. Python mandates that future-imports must appear in the module before any other code except docstrings: